# Split a large file to send parts to host through parallel channels

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, webserver, filezilla

I'm a student of Informatic Engineering, my project is to build a local cloud that produce educational services.
One service is similar to a media center where the cloud has many tutorials in different type of files (video, archives, iso, ...) and clients (students) download any file they need within the range of the local wireless network.

> I'm going to build a web server using PHP Codeigniter framework with FTP service 'FileZilla'

I want to improve the way of download ... to reduce the overhead on server side and to satisfy auto-continues downloading...(when errors occur)
What I need exactly is:

> How to split a file (located in the storage of server) and send each part in a separate channel (using FTP)? Then to reconstruct received parts on client side to build the original file that had been split.

This way is very similar to the process of downloading that done by the application "Internet Download Manager" .. it opens multi channels and each is responsible to one part of the file.

I've tried to state the problem as clear as possible. .. sorry because I'm so beginner to this advanced techniques .. Thank you for everyone help

Comment: You could use BitTorrent for handling file downloads- is easy on your servers, though students will need a BitTorrent client.

Comment: Hope this helps. [link](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/php/merging-a-file-split-for-ftp-upload-using-php/)

Comment: So are you going to code the download in PHP and run multiple scripts/threads, each downloading a part of the file using FTP?

Comment: Thank you for every note >> What I need (on server site) to split a file and put parts in a buffer, then give the client (parts sequence) and run threads to dowload using FTP

Comment: There are some PHP Scripts to split files, but until now I'm confusing if Threads of downloading is the best way ..
if it is, how to give each channels= a special Id in order to give the ability (for client) to re-join parts